# What is the ROI of owning Ether after entering POS?

Tags: ether, proof-of-stake

It's from my understanding you make ETH by owning ETH during POS. And assuming that is true how will ROI be determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At EDCON Vitalik said that the max ROI you can get is 5% per year.

[See here at minute 11.](https://youtu.be/vFK5xRZTcVM?t=11m)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of exact amount, I read somewhere but do not recall where that it was possibly 15% ROI staking 15 ETH.